# How can I use my classes in Behat + Mink?

Tags: behat

I have large (1000+ lines) FeatureContext class and I want to split this file in several logical parts. But I don't know how to create my own classes in Behat. I read docs http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/4.context.html but I don't get it. And in docs example FeatureContext extends BehatContext, but I need FeatureContext extends MinkContext, because Mink doesn't work without it. If you can write example of my own class with function that use Mink and show me how to use this class in FeatureContext that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found right way to use subcontexts (classes) in Behat with Mink http://blog.scur.pl/2012/06/subcontexts-behat-mink/ 
Hope it will help somebody

Answer (score 0):

This configuration should achieve what you need

file: `behat.yml`

```
default:
  suites:
    yourCustomSuite:
      paths:
        - %paths.base%/src/your/bundle/name/Features/YourSuiteName
      contexts:
        - YourBundleName\Contexts\YourContextName
```

file: `YourBundleName\Contexts\YourContextName.php`

```
class YourContextName extends FeatureContext
{
}
```

and let `FeatureContext` extend `\Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext`

Answer (score 0):

Look for [PageObjectExtension](http://behat-page-object-extension.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

> Page object pattern is a way of keeping your context files clean by separating UI knowledge from the actions and assertions.

I've used the PageObjectsExtension in my project and my Contexts look's like this:

```
/**
 * @When /^I order products by "([^"]*)"$/
 *
 * @param $order
 */
public function orderProductsBy($order)
{
    $this->getPage("Catalog")->orderProductsBy($order);
}
```

Configure extension on behat.yml

```
SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension:
      namespaces:
        page: [NS1\Features\Page, NS2\Features\Page]
        element: [NS1\Features\Page\Element, NS2\Features\Page\Element]
```

If you need multiple `Contexts`, you can add it in your behat.yml

```
default:
  suites:
    selenium:
      mink_session: selenium
      mink_javascript_session: selenium
      contexts:
         - Namespace\FeatureContext
         - Namespace\CatalogContext
         - Namespace\CheckoutFinishContext
         - Namespace\CheckoutIndexContext
         - Namespace\HomeContext
         - Namespace\ProductDetailsContext
         - Namespace\CartContext
         - Namespace\CustomerAccountContext
         - Namespace\CustomerLoginContext
         - Namespace\FilterContext
         - Namespace\TelesalesContext
         - Namespace\HelpdeskContext
         - Namespace\FaqContext
         - Namespace\BrandContext
```